# Level of SpatiaLite support on CentoOS 9, specifically spatialite_osm_raw

Tags: spatialite, centos

Running a script on CentOS9 (from within WSL2), I get the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spatialite_osm_raw'
```

on Ubuntu, I was able to install the required tools using

```
sudo apt-get install spatialite-bin
```

and it appears the same functionality may be available in `libspatialite-devel` for centos7 and centos8, according to https://installati.one/centos/7/libspatialite-devel/

However when I try:

```
sudo yum -y install libspatialite-devel
```

or

```
sudo dnf -y install libspatialite-devel
```

I receive

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:09 ago on Wed 20 Jul 2022 09:36:34 AM EDT.
No match for argument: libspatialite-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: libspatialite-devel
```